# How to navigate nested arraylist?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, collections, arraylist

I am using a list to retrieve the values of the fields of a bean class object,on inspecting the list looks like this

```
resultList=ArrayList<E>
[0]=UserDetails
firstname=xxxxxx
lastname=xxxxxx
username=xxxxxx
[1]=TaxDetails
earnings=xxxxxx
savings=xxxxxxx
a/c no=xxxxxx
[2]=null;
[3]=null;
```

Now my question is how can i retrieve the values of the class fields,on fetching the values by using
`resultList.get(i)`, i am getting `UserDetails`,`TaxDetails` which isn't my requirement. How can i navigate further to fetch its fields?? kindly help!

Comment: whta does your `resultList` contains? `UserDetails` or `TaxDetails`?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate like this

```
for (UserDetails object : list) {

 }
```

or

```
  for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
      UserDetails object = list.get(i);     
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String firstname = "",lastname="",username="",earnings="",savings="",ac="";
if(i==0)
{
    firstname = resultList.get(i).firstname;
    lastname = resultList.get(i). lastname;
    username = resultList.get(i). username;
}
else if(i==1)
{
    earnings = resultList.get(i). earnings;
    savings = resultList.get(i). savings;
    ac = resultList.get(i).acno;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast to the relevant `Object` in order to see it's member variables.

A dirty way would just be to do `UserDetails user = (UserDetails)resultList.get(0);`

But that's assuming you know that the `UserDetails` Object is in position 0, and so not best practice.

So you would want to do something like this (If you were iterating through the list) which checks for the type of Object present before doing the cast:

```
for (Object anObject : resultList){
  if (anObject instanceof UserDetails){
      UserDetails user = (UserDetails)anObject;
      String firstname = user.firstname;
  }else if (anObject instanceof TaxDetails){
      TaxDetails tax = (TaxDetails)anObject;
      String earnings = tax.earnings; 
  }
}
```

Of course, if you are just accessing the one value and not iterating you need to do:

```
Object anObject = resultList.get(0);
```

and then perform the `instanceof` comparison and cast as in the loop above.

Answer (score 0):

I think your list got different type elements like UserDetails, TaxDetails ?. First impressionis i dont think it is good idea to keep different of elements in same collection object.

To solve current problem

```
  for (Object obj : resultList) {
      if (obj instanceof UserDetails) {
          UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)obj;
          String firstname = userDetails.getFirstName();
          ...
      } else if (obj instanceof UserDetails) {
         .....
      }
  }
```

I hope it helps